# Deploying Harbor in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, harbor

I'm getting an error

> "error: unable to recognize "harbor.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "v1.10."

What should I use in version variable, while writing the YAML, please tell?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide any solutions that you might have tried already to help resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know about Harbor but if it is related to kubernetes deployment definition yaml, in kubernetes's documentation it says deployment version would be like this:

```
...
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
...
```

links: [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/application/deployment.yaml) and [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/)